# Can't access properties of my Javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js to fetch a single record from my API. I'm getting the record back as an object, I can log the object and see it's properties but I cannot access any of the properties. I just get `undefined`.

```
var template = Template.get({id: id});
$scope.template = template;
...
console.log(template); // displays object
console.log(template.content); // undefined
```

[image: Screenshot of console.log(template);]

**UPDATE**

```
var id = $routeParams.templateId;
var template = Template.get({id: id});
$scope.template = template;

/*** Template placeholders ***/
$scope.updatePlaceholders = function () {
    var placeholders = [];
    var content = template.content;

    console.log(template); // dumps the object in the screenshot
    console.log("content" in template); // displays false

    // get placeholders that match patter
    var match = content.match(/{([A-z0-9]+)}/gmi);
    ...
}

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    $scope.updatePlaceholders();
});
```

Comment: And what does `console.log("content" in template)` display?

Comment: @MaxArt undefined. He has it there as a comment.

Comment: @Yatrix `"content" in template` and `template.content` are two totally different things

Comment: Service calls are asynchronous. The return value is not likely to be your expected data until the ajax call returns.

Comment: @Ian Misunderstood. My bad.

Comment: @JimCote But `console.log` displays the object properties in the moment that it's called. It's strange that it displays `undefined` for a property that it displayed the instruction before.

Comment: @Yatrix No problem. They're quite similar in their purpose, but do different things and *can* reveal more about the problem

Comment: @MaxArt that displays `false`

Comment: It's hard to tell what log matches up with what output.

Comment: @iamjonesy I see you're using Chrome. Is it the same in another browser? Have you enabled the experimental Javascript features, by chance?

Comment: @MaxArt same behaviour in Firefox. Experimental Javascript is disabled

Comment: Chrome shows you the properties of a logged object as they are **at expansion time**, *not* as the object existed at log time. At log time, `template` doesn't have a `content` property, but by the time you get around to expanding the log entry for inspection, the asynchronous request has completed, and it does have a `content` property.

Comment: Updated my question to include my code

Comment: @apsillers Neat. I've never noticed. But first it display a summary of the object properties, and the shown values are the ones at calling time. Confusing behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for your HTTP request to complete, then specify what to do in the callback. In this case I've taken it a step further and added a listener to your template object so there's no callback dependency between updatePlaceholders and your resource.

```
var id = $routeParams.templateId;
var template = Template.get({id: id}, function(res) {
    $scope.template = template;
});

/*** Template placeholders ***/
$scope.updatePlaceholders = function () {
    var placeholders = [];
    var content = $scope.template.content;

    console.log($scope.template); 
    console.log("content" in $scope.template); 

    // get placeholders that match patter
    var match = content.match(/{([A-z0-9]+)}/gmi);
    ...
}

$scope.$watch('template', function(newValue){
    if(newValue) $scope.updatePlaceholders();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for improving this! Works great!